# Composite c1 Odata Pageresult

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api, c1-cms

I'm having difficulties using Odata in combination with PageResult.
I get the correct result, 5 items if I set [Queryable(PageSize=5)]

but no nextlink, which I expect, so I can get the next results of page 2 for example.

Composite C1 uses it's own XML datastore, and I think that's the core of the problem.

All of the examples I found for OData V3 (the version which is installed if you use http://www.composite.net/Products/Add-ons/All/Composite.AspNet.WebAPI)
Tell me to just use [Queryable(PageSize=5)] and it should work out of the box.
But they all use entity framework, which I don't and I think that's where it breaks.

this is my result, without the nextlink:

```
<Data>
    <ImageItem>
        <Id>1eeb46e3-1446-45e8-bab2-03ccb637b2ab</Id>
        <Title/>
        <SubTitle/>
    </ImageItem>
    <ImageItem>
        <Id>1eeb46e3-1446-45e8-bab2-03ccb637b2ab</Id>
        <Title/>
        <SubTitle/>
    </ImageItem>
    <ImageItem>
        <Id>1eeb46e3-1446-45e8-bab2-03ccb637b2ab</Id>
        <Title/>
        <SubTitle/>
    </ImageItem>
    <ImageItem>
        <Id>1eeb46e3-1446-45e8-bab2-03ccb637b2ab</Id>
        <Title/>
        <SubTitle/>
    </ImageItem>
    <ImageItem>
        <Id>1eeb46e3-1446-45e8-bab2-03ccb637b2ab</Id>
        <Title/>
        <SubTitle/>
    </ImageItem>
</Data>
```

Code:

```
    public class ImagesController : ApiController
    {
        public PageResult Get(ODataQueryOptions options)
        {
            using (var c = new DataConnection())
            {
                var querySettings = new ODataQuerySettings() { PageSize = 20 };

                var filtered = options.ApplyTo(c.Get(), querySettings).Cast().ToList().AsQueryable();
                return new PageResult(filtered, Request.GetNextPageLink(), 20);
            }
        }
    }
```

Request.GetNextPageLink() returns http://xx.local/api/images?$skip=5

variable filtered has a list of 19 imageitems. and filtered.Count() returns 19 as well.

Does someone have a suggestion or even a solution?
The composite C1 installation is a bare bones one, with no extra handlers.
Composite C1 4.2 Update 1, Build no. 4.2.5287.17495

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the [Queryable] attribute, it prevents proper rendering of a  PageResult response.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it didn't work out though.

I updated the question with the code I have right now.
I set 20 hardcoded, just to make sure paging should work.